# Netlogo : calling a procedure after opening a file

Tags: netlogo, procedure

Here-below is the code for opening a file, reading it and writing it into a list (inspired from another discussion) :

```
to setup
  reset-timer
  ; first, we load the database file
  ; We check to make sure the file exists first
  ifelse ( file-exists? "AT_data.txt" )
  [
    ; We are saving the data into a list, so it only needs to be loaded once.
    set AT-data []
    file-open "AT_data.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ]
    [
      ; file-read gives variables stored in a double list
      ; Each iteration we append the next three-tuple to the current list: ID AT1 AT2
      set AT-data sentence AT-data (list (list file-read file-read file-read))
    ]
    user-message "File loading complete!"
    file-close
   ;; when adding this, the procedure is running endlessly, to be checked
   ;; ask patches [ assign-data ]

    ]
  [ user-message "There is no AT_data.txt file in current directory!" ]

  file-close-all

  print timer
end
```

As I wrote as a comment, when I call the next procedure `[assign-data]`, the procedure `[assign-data]` runs endlessly. I setup a timer in the `[assign-data]` procedure and I see that it is running over and over again. When I run `[assign-data]` on its own, it is working appropriatly, only once.

I tried with a `stop` after `[assign-data]` but it is not working.

**There must be something that I did not get yet about the use of Netlogo, do you know what it is ?**

Here is the code of the `assign-data`procedure (there are 2 choices, the second is running faster)

```
to assign-farmers1
  reset-timer

  ask patches with [seed = 1] [
  set death last (first (filter [current-inner-list -> (item 0 current-inner-list = ID_farm)] AT-data))
  set age item 1  (first (filter [current-inner-list -> (item 0 current-inner-list = ID_farm)] AT-data))
  ]

  print timer

end


to assign-data2
  reset-timer
  ask patches with [seed = 1] [
    let i 1
    while [i < length AT-data] [
      let current-inner-list item i AT-data
      ifelse (ID_farm = item 0 current-inner-list)
        [ set age item 1 current-inner-list set death item 2 current-inner-list
          stop]
        [ set i i + 1 ]
      ]
      ]
  print timer
end
```

**->** that lead me to another question : how to stop a simulation from running endlessly ? I tried with `stop` in the command center but it is not working.

Thanks for you time.

---

**HERE IS A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**
(not sure if I should leave the beginning of the question)
AT_data.txt is a file made of 3 col where the first goes from 1 to 100, second and third are just random numbers.

```
globals [
  AT-data
  ]

patches-own [
  ID
  AT1
  AT2
  seed
]

to setup
  ;; here I just create patches with different values that also appear in the list
  ca
  ask patches [ set seed random 10 set ID random 100
    ifelse (seed = 4)
    [ set pcolor orange] [set pcolor white]
  ]
end

to load
  reset-timer
  ; first, we load the database file
  ; We check to make sure the file exists first
  ifelse ( file-exists? "AT_data.txt" )
  [
    ; We are saving the data into a list, so it only needs to be loaded once.
    set AT-data []
    file-open "AT_data.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ]
    [
      ; file-read gives variables stored in a double list
      ; Each iteration we append the next three-tuple to the current list: ID AT1 AT2
      set AT-data sentence AT-data (list (list file-read file-read file-read))
    ]
    user-message "File loading complete!"
    file-close
   ;; when adding this, the procedure is running endlessly, to be checked
   ask patches [ assign-data ]
   stop
    ]
  [ user-message "There is no AT_data.txt file in current directory!" ]

  file-close-all

  print timer
end


to assign-data
  reset-timer
  ask patches with [seed = 4] [
    let i 1
    while [i < length AT-data] [
      let current-inner-list item i AT-data
      ifelse (ID = item 0 current-inner-list)
        [ set AT1 item 1 current-inner-list set AT2 item 2 current-inner-list
          stop]
        [ set i i + 1 ]
      ]
      ]
  print timer
end
```

Comment: We need to see what code there is inside `assign-data`. Also, if doable a [mre] would be needed. But really, as the question is on `assign-data`, that is the essential part.

Comment: I'm working on a reproducible example. Thank you anyway for your comment Matteo.

Comment: I added a reproducible example, which is also running endlessly when `assign-data` procedure is called from the  `load` procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the run is endless and not exponential? You `ask patches` to `assign-data` and in `assign-data` you use `ask patches` again. That means that every single patch is checking every single patch and letting the qualified patch go through the loop, which can take a while.

Comment: Indeed... I tried first to call `assign-data` by just writing it but it was not calling it (and not asking the patches to call it) but it is working now with the example I prepared. Thank you LeirsW for pointing this

Comment: You're welcome. Oh and I don't think Netlogo has a way to manually force a loop to end. I generally just save the program beforehand and forcefully closeNetlogo when it is stuck.

Comment: I just checked again, sometimes it is enough to just go to the code tab and make a single change there. That generally also aborts the run.